# Angular binding delayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to get the x and y coordinates on click and display them in the input boxes. But the values are visible only after I click first on the div to get the coordinates and then click in the one of the input boxes. My goal is to populate the input boxes when the user click for the x and y coordinates.

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm >
    <label>Vertical</label>
    <input ng-model="pdfVertical">
</md-input-container>

<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm >
    <label>Horisontal</label>
    <input ng-model="pdfHorisontal">
</md-input-container>


$("#overlayDiv").click(function (event) {
    $scope.pdfVertical = event.clientY;
    $scope.pdfHorisontal = event.clientX;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$scope.$apply()` at the end of the click event, to refresh the view. Here check out this example:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $("#overlayDiv").click(function(event) {
        $scope.pdfVertical = event.clientY;
        $scope.pdfHorisontal = event.clientX;
        $scope.$apply();
    });
}
```

```css
#overlayDiv{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div id="overlayDiv">
            <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
                <label>Vertical</label>
                <input ng-model="pdfVertical">
            </md-input-container>
            <br>
            <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
                <label>Horisontal</label>
                <input ng-model="pdfHorisontal">
            </md-input-container>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a jQuery & Angular loading order problem. 
Make sure you load jQuery before Angularjs. Take a look at this reference:

[Loading jQuery after AngularJS (instead of before)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777108/loading-jquery-after-angularjs-instead-of-before)